# VBA Open another workbook and sheet with variables

Tags: vba, excel

I could not find an answer to this yet:

I have a sheet with the Customer name in Cell A2 and the product code in Cell B2.
I have a file location "C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Customer BOMS\" with a workbook for each Customer. In these workbooks, there is a tab per product code with the formulation to make the product.

What I need to do is to tell the Macro to open the workbook for the specific customer in cell A2 and to then go to the tab in cell B2.

I have been able to open the workbook, but not the sheet.
Here is my code:

```
Range("A2").Select

Dim CName As String

Dim PCode As String

Dim BOM As Workbook

Dim ws As Worksheet

CName = ActiveCell.Value

PCode = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

Set BOM = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Customer BOMS\" & CName & ".xlsm")

Set ws = BOM.Sheets(Range(PCode))
```

Comment: If you want to go to the sheet, you need to activate it with ws.activate

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me a compile error: Method or Data Member not found.

Comment: Try to change this line `Set ws = BOM.Sheets(Range(PCode))` to `Set ws = BOM.Sheets(PCode)`

Comment: Please be more specific and maybe you could also show your changed code.

Comment: In the 'Range(PCode)' the PCode is a value of the cell and compiler is expecting a range address. Try changing the  `PCode = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value` to `PCode = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address'.

Comment: So I have changed my code to the following. It doesn't throw out an error anymore, but it doesn't go to the required sheet either :(...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Range("A2").Select

Dim CName As String

Dim PCode As String

Dim BOM As Workbook

Dim ws As Worksheet

CName = ActiveCell.Value

PCode = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

Set BOM = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Customer BOMS\" & CName & ".xlsm")

Set ws = BOM.Sheets(PCode)
 ws.activate
```